# List all the elements of $A = \{ n \in \mathbb{Z} \mid \frac{n^2-n+2}{2n+1} \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Tags: number-theory

I was given the following set $A = \{ n \in \mathbb{Z} \mid \frac{n^2-n+2}{2n+1} \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

I have to list all the elements of $A$.

I started using the Euclidean division:

$$n^2-n+2=(2n+1)(\frac{1}{2}n-\frac{3}{4}) + \frac{11}{4}$$

In order to eliminate the fractions, I multiplied the whole expression with 4:

$$4(n^2-n+2)=(2n+1)(2n-3) + 11$$

I´m stuck here, maybe I´m on the wrong way. Could anyone give me some hints how can I approach this problem. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As have you have noticed,
$$
4\frac{n^2-n+2}{2n+1}= 2n-3+ \frac{11}{2n+1}
$$
Therefore, if $\dfrac{n^2-n+2}{2n+1}$ is an integer, then so is $\dfrac{11}{2n+1}$.

This leaves very few candidates for $n$.

You need to check each candidate to see whether $\dfrac{n^2-n+2}{2n+1}$ is an integer.

Comment: I thank you for the elegant observation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer based on the hint of @lhf

$$4\frac{n^2-n+2}{2n+1}= 2n-3+ \frac{11}{2n+1}$$
$$4\frac{n^2-n+2}{2n+1} \in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow \frac{11}{2n+1} \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 2n+1 \in D_{11} \Leftrightarrow 2n+1 \in \{-11, -1, 1 ,  11\}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 2n \in \{-12, -2, 0 ,  10\}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow n \in \{-6, -1, 0 ,  5\}$$

### $$\Rightarrow A = \{-6, -1, 0 , 5\}$$

---

Another approach:

$$\frac{n^2-n+2}{2n+1} \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow n^2-n+2 \equiv 0[2n+1]$$
$$\Rightarrow 4(n^2-n+2) \equiv 0[2n+1]$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (2n+1)(2n-3) + 11 \equiv 0[2n+1]$$
$$\Rightarrow 11 \equiv 0[2n+1]$$
$$\Rightarrow (2n+1) \mid 11$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (2n+1) \in D_{11}$$

---

Another approach:

$$4(n^2-n+2)=(2n+1)(2n-3) + 11$$
According to the successive division:
$$4(n^2-n+2)\wedge (2n+1)=(2n+1) \wedge 11$$
We have $$(\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}) 4 \wedge (2n+1)= 1$$
Since $(\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}) n^2 - n + 2 \in \mathbb{Z^*}$, then
$$4 \wedge (2n+1)= 1 \Rightarrow 4(n^2-n+2)\wedge (2n+1) = (n^2-n+2)\wedge (2n+1)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (n^2-n+2)\wedge (2n+1) = (2n+1) \wedge 11$$
We have $ \frac{n^2-n+2}{2n+1} \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $(2n+1) \mid (n^2-n+2)$
$$\Leftrightarrow (n^2-n+2)\wedge (2n+1) = \mid2n+1\mid$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (2n+1) \wedge 11 = \mid2n+1\mid$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (2n+1) \in D_{11} $$